# Ext.application and Ext.direct: data doesnt get displayed

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am new to ExtJS and have written a sample App using Ext.application with Ext.direct. I configured my model as shown below

```
Ext.define('AM.model.UserModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    alias : 'widget.userModel',
    fields: ['SlNo','name']
    proxy: {
        type: 'direct',
        directfn: HelloWorld.getGridDetails
    }
});
```

and I am using grid Panel as shown below

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.List' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.userlist',    
    title : 'Users',        
    initComponent: function() {
        this.store = {
            model:'AM.model.UserModel',
            autoload:true,
        };
        this.columns = [
                        {
                            header: 'SlNo', 
                            dataIndex: 'SlNo', 
                            width:100,
                            disabled:false 
                        },
                        {
                            header: 'Name',  
                            dataIndex: 'name', 
                            width:150
                        }
        ];
       this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

finally my index.js looks like this

```
 Ext.require('Ext.direct.*', function() {
    Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider(Ext.app.REMOTING_API);
  });   
    Ext.require([ 'AM.view.user.List','AM.model.UserModel']);
    Ext.application({
        name: 'AM',
        appFolder:'myApp',
        launch: function() {
            Ext.Direct.addProvider(Ext.app.DirectAPI);                                 
            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                items: {
                    xtype: 'userlist',
                    width: 552
                },
                renderTo: Ext.getBody()
            });
        }
    });
```

The data I receive when I call `HelloWorld.getGridDetails` from `index.js` is as shown below

```
 action: "HelloWorld",
    method: "getGridDetails",
    result: [
     {slNo:2, name:"patton"},
     {slNo:3, name:"Omar N Bradely"},
     {slNo:1, name:"Sam Manekshaw"}
   ],   
    tid: 1,
    type: "rpc"
```

The problem is that I am not able to load data in to the grid i.e, The direct method `HelloWorld.getGridDetails` is not at all getting called when the grid is displayed. Am I missing something? Can anyone of you please help?

Thanks
Kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured out the solution for this. Though it doesnt make sense now, better late than never. I need to modify the following in the index.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Api.js"></script>
 **<script type="text/javascript">Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider(Ext.app.REMOTING_API);</script>**
 <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

After adding

```
<script type="text/javascript">Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider(Ext.app.REMOTING_API);</script>
```

before index.js. It started working.

Comment: I'm wondering if I can use your assistance with our implementation of Ext.Direct with ExtJS 4 sometime this week?  Would you be willing to have a quick call?  I've done quite a bit of research on the subject and am attempting the upgrade right now.  I'm just struggling with the API descriptor file and this Ext.app.REMOTING_API provider.  I've been using a custom AJAX proxy for over a year, but it broke during our upgrade from 4.1.0 to 4.2.1.